# Differential equation equilibrium points

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Find the equilibrium points of the system

$$\dfrac{dx}{dt} = y \\ \dfrac{dy}{dt} = x-x^3-y.$$

sketch the phase portrait.

Comment: Did you write this properly? I am not sure you wrote $dx/dt$ correctly. Also, can you please share your thoughts?

Comment: I just realize I did not write it properly.

Comment: Add any perspective. Are we allowed to use linearization techniques by way of the Jacobian for example.

Comment: dx/dt=y dy/dt= x-x^3-y

Comment: I think linearization technique can be used she did not specify in this assignment

Comment: @Racquel, it would be appropriate to share what you have attempted so far and in particular what part of solving this problem you need help with.

Comment: @Spencer I have not attempted anything yet because I have no idea where to start I was looking up how to find the equilibrium points but I have yet to come across a question like this. I don't know if I should solve it separately or what

Comment: @Racquel, ok thats fine. The first place to start is to make sure you understand what the question is asking for. Do you know the definition of an equillibrium point? The usual definition would be an ordered pair $(x,y)$ which makes both $dx/dt=0$ and $dy/dt=0$

Comment: @spencer thank you spencer

Answer (score 3):

Hints outlined.

- To find the critical points, we want to find where we simultaneously have $x'$ and $y'$ equal to zero.
- We find three critical points $(x, y) = (-1, 0), (0,0), (1, 0)$.
- We can now find the Jacobian matrix and analyze each critical point for it's type at those three critical points (see Phase Portrait below).
- We can draw the phase portrait from the above and by forming $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ and doing some analysis.

The phase portrait is:

[image]

Comment: ooooo so the phase line was sketched from (-1,1)(0,0) (1,0)? she didn't teach us this in class

Comment: Review these notes and work it (no phase line is drawn, it comes from analyzing the critical points and their type and then following the notes for direction arrows). http://www.math.purdue.edu/~xiaj/teaching/304.10f/phaseplane.pdf

Comment: thanks! I will do that

Comment: Always teaching! +1